# How can I use a variable in a class for changing its value globally in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-4

How can I use a variable in a class, such as if I  change the value of the variable from member function then its value will be changed globally . How can I do this?

Comment: If you have to do this, it sounds like you have a design problem.

Comment: use `session` the simplest thing one could do

Comment: Most people are trying to *avoid* global state. :)

Comment: Use a property and make the class globally available.

Comment: I am new in laravel and PHP also. Yes I have design problem.But I want to recover it. Thank's for reply. You guys  are so kind.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are searching for this:

```
class abcd {
public $value;
function __construct($value) {
    $this->value        = $value;
}
public function change ($change)
{
     $this->value = $change;
}

}
$new= new abcd (123);
print_r($new);
$new->change (546);
print_r($new);
```

Answer (score 0):

first.php

```
<?php    
class first {    
    private $name;
    function __construct() {
        $this->name="name";
    }

    function  changeName(){
        $this->name="newName";
    }

    function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }    
}    
?>
```

second.php

```
<?php
    include 'first.php';
    $firstObject=new first;
    echo $firstObject->getName().'<br>';
    $firstObject->changeName();
    echo $firstObject->getName();

?>
```